# Filter out traffic clicking a certain link on website

Tags: google-analytics

My website contains a "login" link to the customer dashboard which is on another domain. We are on our way to freshen up the Google Analytics dashboard statistics and want to filter out the traffic which is clicking this link on our website from the dashboard statistics.

We tried a few options through filtering, but I think this has to be custom. Is there anyone who can help us with this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Well the easiest thing here would be making a bitmap session or user-level custom dimension (or a normal one, I'm just trying to save space) and indicate in it whether the user clicked the login link. It can be done very easily in GTM.

After that, you additionally filter the traffic in your dashboard by that custom dimension.